# Does a disabled person with learning difficulties unable to generate income have to pay zakat

Tags: zakat

AA.

I know you have answered a similar question but I need further clarification.

A 19 year old girl has learning difficulties (bur not insane) and will never really be able to earn an income. The learning difficulties arose as a result of medical negligence.

She has been given lump sum compensation to cover her care needs throughout her life.

Does she have to pay zakat on this lump sum payment?

JA

TS

Comment: This is an interesting situation...

Answer (score 1):

The compensation she received is considered as wealth/property she owns.  The zakat is only due one the wealth she does not touch for a lunar year.

Since she will be using this compensation fully for medical care, which is unpredictable, then she does not need to give zakat on it since it is a sum that has a needs attached to it.

If it was extra compensation of which she would not use and put it as savings for a year, then on the savings she would need to give zakat.  Otherwise, if she will use the money then it is not considered zakat liable.

She may even be able to receive zakat from others since she cannot take care of herself due to medical needs.

Comment: It would've been nice if you've provided some references.